# Token de acceso a la app Facebokk

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Quiero saber si hay una forma de obtener un token de acceso a la página apartir de un token de acceso a la aplicación.

Para obtener el token de acceso a la aplicación estoy haciendo un request a esta url
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={}&client_secret={}&grant_type=client_credentials".format(app_id, secret_key)

Comment: donde tienes el código para ese token?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta pero, si sirve de algo, lo estoy implementando en python y no lo he subido a ningún repositorio de github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes ir a https://developers.facebook.com donde debes crear el app y te va a dar los datos que necesitas. Obvio primero hay que registrar una cuenta.

Comment: Ya tengo la aplicación creada y los datos de app_id y secret_key. El problema es que en la documentación del api no encuentro una manera de cambiar el token de acceso a la aplicación por un token de usuario

Comment: El token de usuario se genera cuando el usuario permite al app acceder a su información de facebook, por lo tanto debes tener una forma de loguear a una persona para que este permita el acceso. Por ejemplo mientras iba haciendo purebas con el api de FB usé 2 cuentas(una personal y la de admin en FB developer)

Comment: Con esto te quiero decir que en la app en la que trabajaba habia 3 formas de crear una cuenta dentro del sistema. Ingresando datos en un formulario, facebook y google. En tu caso me imagino que estas haciendo esto en una vista

Comment: Yo estoy trabajando mi aplicación con una sola cuenta de FB developer, la forma en como un usuario se puede loguear en mi aplicación es:
"Crear un proceso de inicio de sesión de forma manual"

Comment: Creo que debes editar tu pregunta y aumentar todo lo que hemos comentado, puesto que así la comunidad entera te podra entender mejor. Si puedes agrega codigo, imagenes, etc para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, lo voy a hacer para que así me puedan ayudar mejor